# What's Wrong With My Code? (ValueError: I/O operation on closed file)

Tags: python

Can Someone Explain to me what is wrong with my code? I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:\LineRep.py", line
>   15, in module:
>       for line in File2:
>  ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

My Code:

```
import os, Tkinter, tkFileDialog
root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()
dirprompt = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()

File = open (dirprompt, 'r')
File2 = open (dirprompt + 'temp', 'w')
for line in File:
    File2.write(line.replace(',', ' '))
File.close()
File2.close()

names = []
for line in File2:
    names.append(line)
print names
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are iterating over File2 after you call File2.close()